# MS SQL Join function anomaly

Tags: sql, outer-join

I ran this query, which looks correct. However, I noticed that the that the output looks like a bunch of duplicate text (See image below). Is something wrong with the code?
If so, how do I correct this anomaly

```
SELECT          sv.FirstName + '  ' + sv.LastName 'SalesPersonName',
                st.[Group] 'TerritoryGroup',st.Name 'TerritoryName',
                StateProvinceName 'ShipState',
                YEAR(OrderDate) 'Order Year',MONTH(OrderDate) 'Order Month',
                (soh.TotalDue) Total
FROM                Person.StateProvince ps
LEFT OUTER JOIN         Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh 
ON              ps.TerritoryID=soh.TerritoryID
LEFT OUTER JOIN         Sales.SalesTerritory st
ON              soh.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID
LEFT OUTER JOIN         Sales.vSalesPerson sv
ON              soh.SalesPersonID = sv.BusinessEntityID
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check the effect of using `INNER` instead of `LEFT OUTER` joins. If this does not help, it'd help us to help you, if you provided more detail.

Comment: Thanks Abecee, but INNER JOIN and JOIN did not change the outcome. What other detail do you need?

Comment: Definition of relevant parts of the tables, sample data, and expected results for this data… However, if you select all columns from the four tables - does it still look like duplicate rows? If not, adding `DISTINCT`to your query might clear the duplication.

Comment: Thanks, once again Abecee. While fiddling with the code, I came up with a solution that works. Check in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query ran with no repeat rows

```
SELECT      sv.FirstName+'  '+sv.LastName 'SalesPersonName',st.[Group]     'TerritoryGroup',st.Name 'TerritoryName', ps.Name 'ShipState', 
    YEAR(OrderDate) 'OrderYear',MONTH(OrderDate) 'OrderMonth',soh.TotalDue
FROM        Person.Address pa
INNER JOIN  Person.StateProvince ps
ON      pa.StateProvinceID = ps.StateProvinceID 
INNER JOIN  Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
ON      pa.AddressID = soh.BillToAddressID 
AND     pa.AddressID = soh.ShipToAddressID 
INNER JOIN  Sales.SalesTerritory st
ON      ps.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID 
AND     ps.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID 
AND     soh.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID 
AND     soh.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID 
CROSS JOIN  Sales.vSalesPerson sv
```

Comment: This is a completely different query and can be hardly considered as an answer to your original question.

Comment: Thanks. You may be right. However, this gives me ALL the information I need from each specified table. Therefore, this IS the right query for my purposes.